# Where to keep Angular 2 Integration test files?

Tags: angular

I have created Angular 2 project through Angular CLI and updated component (app.component.ts) and corresponding component test file (app.component.spec.ts). Here, updated component (app.component.ts) to gets the data from 'Angular 2 Service' (which communicates with REST API).

I would like to write an Integration test cases about the component (app.component.ts) and want to create separate file from normal unit test cases file (app.component.spec.ts). Can you please let me know the best practices to keep the integration test files (folder path and file naming convention) and any suggested way to run them like 'npm test'.

Answer (score 0):

You can organise them by:

- User Story - BDD

  ```
  describe('As an admin user I need to be able to view my jobs')
  ```

OR

- Routing

  ```
  describe('/login')
  ```

Organise according to browser URL.

I prefer the latter.

Comment: Hello Danday, Thanks for your quick response.I am looking for guide lines to maintain unit test files and integration test files separately.Thanks in Advance for your help, your help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: unit test files should appear in the same location as the files they are testing. so if my file is locator.js then in the same folder i will have a test file called locator.spec.js (or .ts in angular2 world) - this is not possible with integration tests which are E2E tests since they are not testing a single file but are testing the system as a whole.